# select option angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

hello the problem related to the select option, the person's property is male M, in the select there must be the possibility to select the sex and change it with F.
property is for man `entity.person.sex = 'M'`
and for woman is `entity.person.sex = 'F'`

html

```
<span >
    <span >
        <span >Sesso</span>
        <span ></span>
        <select name='gender'>
            <option [value]='' selected>{{entity.person.sex}}</option>
            <option [ngValue]="">{{}}</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke a function for the change event:

```
 <select name='gender' (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
      <option ....
 </select>
```

Component:

```
selectChangeHandler (event: any) {
    //update the ui
    this.entity.person.sex = event.target.value;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it the angular way and bind the select to your model.

In your HTML (`...component.html`):

```html
    <span>
        <span>
            <span>Sesso</span>
            <select name='gender' [(ngModel)]="entity.person.sex">
                <option value='M'>Male</option>
                <option value='F'>Female</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </span>
```

In your TypeScript (`...component.ts`):

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  entity =  {
    person: {
      sex: 'M'
    }
  };
  // the rest of your component...
}
```

I've created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-bind-test) so you can test it and play around.

Comment: problem is that value of entity is dimanimic for person for example  person.sex = 'M' for luca and for another entity for example monica is  person.sex = 'F'

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, and if it is we need more info. How are you loading your `entity` object?

Comment: and the default value in present in a select rappresent the object

Comment: "entity":{
   "person":{
      "name":"CARLA"      "sex":"F"
   }
}

Comment: "entity":{
   "person":{
      "name":"MAURO"      "sex":"M"
   }
}

Comment: I have updated the StackBlitz example to take into account multiple persons like you have described. Hopefully it will help you, otherwise I'm afraid I don't understand your problem.